# Find Point from a Given Point (x,y) up to half of the width of a rectangle C#

Tags: c#, math

I don't know how to express my problem in layman's term but supposed I have a rectangle that starts in Point (0,0) and its width is 32 (any measurement can be feet or pixel), I want to know what Point(x,y) (straight line) from StartPoint(0,0) up to half of the width. Is it possible in C#? Please see the attached image for illustration. Link of screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC962.png

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShapeDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startPoint = new Point(0,0);
            var width = 32;//32 feet or pixel or any measurement
            //var targetPoint=startPoint up to 16 (half of width or 32/2)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Please see Screenshot here]

Comment: You need to explain this better, it's unclear what you want. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to generate a random point inside the rectangle, with the constraint that it must be found in the "left" half of the rectangle? Or are you looking for the midpoint of the top vertex? Why do you say "up to" 16?

Comment: Is this what you need? int midPoint = (int) (width/2f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
var width = 32;

var targetPoint = new Point(startPoint.X + (width / 2), startPoint.Y);
```